# Convert Map to String with custom delimiter (Groovy)

Tags: groovy

I have a JSON:

```
{
  "order_id" : 1,
  "order_item" : "PS5",
  "item_specs" : {
    "item_price" : "$499",
    "item_available" : false,
    "item_description" : "Console"
  },
  "sale_date" : "2020-10-20",
}
```

I want to transform Map inside json to String with delimiter `&` and put it to JSON back is another parameter:

```
item_specs" : {
    "item_price" : "$499",
    "item_available" : false,
    "item_description" : "Console"
  }
```

After this transformation my JSON should like this:

```
{
  "order_id" : 1,
  "order_item" : "PS5",
  "item_specs" : {
    "item_price" : "$499",
    "item_available" : false,
    "item_description" : "Console"
  },
  "items_as_string": "item_price=$499&item_available=false&item_description=Console"
  "sale_date" : "2020-10-20",
}
```

How to do it with Groovy?

Comment: what is the problem? just in case you are looking how to work with json in groovy: https://groovy-lang.org/json.html

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.  Also this looks more
like url encoding for query params, which often means more than just
joining strings.

Comment: I parsed JSON with `JsonSlurper`, then used `JsonBuilder` on it and used `builder.content.item_as_string = builder.content.item_spec.toMapString()`. I don't know groovy at all.
P.S. It's not url encoding for query params.

Comment: @hsadik Might still need quoting.  What happens if key/values contain an `=` or `&`?

Comment: If key/values contain = or & it should be an invalid key or value and should be skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
map.collect{ k,v -> k+'='+v }.join('&')
```